# How to do the UI for Android in Xamarin Starter Edition with VisualStudio 2015 Community?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Thanks in advance!

I haven't tried the free *VisualStudio 2015 Community Edition*, but I know that it has *Xamarin Starter Edition* included. I read that it has `Xamirin.Android/iOS` but not `Xamarin.Forms`, also that there are certain restrictions.

1. I wonder how to do the UI in the Starter Edition if it doesn't include `Xamarin.Forms`. What technology is being used to do the UI in this case **(for Android)**? Is it MVVM oriented?
2. If it is somehow possible to do the UI for Android in the starter edition, what UI development approach/pattern is best, so that it's best to migrate to Xamarin.Forms later on? Is it classic MVVM? Or may be it's even easier, so that I will be able to use the same say XAML code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to design a fully native Android UI using Xamarin. Read the [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/).

If you want to use the MVVM pattern then you should consider using MvvmCross. Read the [tutorials](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-Tutorials), see the [sample codes](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials) or [watch the N+1 videos](http://mvvmcross.blogspot.de/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is _MvvmCross_ a big library? I'm asking because there is a size limit in the starter edition + i'll need to use another side library to work with _SQLite_... So i wonder if it will be possible to do my project in the starter edition...

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to create an entire app using Xamarin Starter. The limitations are really strong. Starter seems to be more a demo version then everything else. Maybe it's better to take a look at [MVVMLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). In case you want to test what's possible with Xamarin you should consider using the trial version of Xamarin.Android.